# Json from ASP.Net webservice using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

i want to generate the below json from SQL database table using ASP.Net webservice. then i will visualaize in d3.js.

what i need is how to convert datatable into below json format using C#.

my sql query just like

```
select SiteName,status,conformed,total from
[Output].SIT_W10_Application_Readiness_overview_siteview
```

sql output:

```
location        status      value           total
111, Valencia   conformed   1               26
111, Valencia   Testing     22              26
```

Code i tried:

```
public class Propm234
    {
        public string SiteName{ get; set; }
        public string status{ get; set; }
        public string conformed{ get; set; }
        public string total{ get; set; }

    }


    List<Propm234> p91 = new List<Propm234> { };

    [WebMethod]

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public string get_SITAppr()
    {
        string query = "select SiteName,status,conformed,total from
[Output].SIT_W10_Application_Readiness_overview_siteview";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        string a = GetSITData11(cmd);
        DataSet ds = GetSITData1(cmd);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Propm234 pp = new Propm234();
            pp.SiteName= item["SiteName"].ToString();
            pp.status = item["ws"].ToString();
            pp.conformed= item["W10Tested"].ToString();
            pp.total= item["TotalPackage"].ToString();
            p91.Add(pp);

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string ss = jss.Serialize(p91);
        return ss;
    }
```

current code returns:

```
[
   {
     "location":"111, Valencia, (VE),SEDCS349",
     "status":"conformed",
     "value":"1",
     "total":"26"}
   }
]
```

but what i am expecting a json is from C# webservice is below

```
jsonData = [
               {
                 "key": "Total",
                 "values": [
                             {"label": "111, Valencia", "value": 26},

                           ]
              },
              {
                "key": "Conformed",
                "values": [
                            {"label": "111, Valencia", "value": 1}                              
                         ]
             },
             {
                "key": "Testing",
                "values": [
                             {"label": "111, Valencia", "value": 22}
                         ]
             }
             ];
```

Comment: thats great. what code have you written to solve the problem?

Comment: see my code added..

Comment: if it is python i can do it easily...i am new to C# ....please dont degrade...

Comment: so what's wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: thats a sample code i tried but i want an out put what i mentioned..

Comment: the current code will give result as just json string..  [{"ProductName":"111, Valencia, (VE), SEDCS349","Version":"Win10 Ready","Vendor":"1","MaterialNumber":"26"},{"ProductName":"111, Valencia, (VE), SEDCS349","Version":"Not Started","Vendor":"22","MaterialNumber":"26"},{"

Comment: but i am looking a hierarchical (parent and child ) json sets

Comment: hope u understood Mr Daniel A

Comment: @sen please add the json that the current code is returning to the question.  And don't be degrading when people are trying to help.  You didn't include any code that you wrote in your question and Mr. Daniel was correct to point that out.  And you don't know that it was he who downvoted you anyway.

Comment: Dear, Dckuehn, i have updated the current code's output..please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JSON.NET Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).  I suspect you have something in your `Propm234()` class doing something like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
public string Vendor { get; set; }
```

But to try and answer your question, if you want your JSON to look like your first example, your C# object has to look like that as well.

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

You obviously don't have to use a dictionary for your values, if you want to make that whatever type you want.  But the moral of the story is that if you don't serialize a List, you're not going to get a list.  You're getting one value because that's all your serializing, and you don't specificy a `Key` object, or a `Values` object.

If you don't want to do specific JSON Classes for your serialization, you can use anonymous objects, like:

```
Object jsonObj = new {
    key = "conformed",
    values = Propm234List.Select(s => 
        new { 
            label = s.label,
            value = s.value
        }
    )
}

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string ss = jss.Serialize(jsonObj );
return ss;
```

Comment: Dear dckuehn, i tried with my mentioned sql result but i didnt get the expected result. also i am confused how to implement your logic. please help me

Comment: @sen I added the serialization bit.  Do you understand my point though? Your code does not split the values retrieved from your SQL statement into Key-Value groups.  My code tries to show you how to do that with "conformed".  You'll also have to do with with "total" and "testing" and combine those into a single key-value list, and serialize that whole list to get your desired results.

Comment: ya...finally i got and achieved the result..thanks lot..